# Magento Catalog Blank Page Problem

Tags: catalog, page

My administrator page on add you site product or added products view problem. Catalog page blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to enable errors:

- Go to the Magento root directory
- Open the index.php file
- In the index.php file, uncomment the following lines:

`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

- Enable the Developer Mode. This can be done in two ways:

*1. Add the following command at the beginning of the index.php file:*

`$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true`

*2.  Add the following line to the .htaccess file*

`SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"`

This way you can debug your errors.

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works for you.

Happy Coding...

Comment: Sorry, problems apply. Catalog > Manage Product blank page.

Comment: Are you still unable to see the errors? After doing the above steps which I have called out in the answer.

Comment: The problem is not to appear in the notification. There are products on the page but it looks blank page

Comment: This blank page comes up due to small php errors. From the look I can only guess (not sure) that, its  GRID of products. There is some element missing or variable or object error that's making the display blank.